# Could not find installable ISAM error in VBA for .accdb file

Tags: excel, oledbconnection, vba

I am trying to connect MS Excel VBA program to MS access database.
While I am trying to access *.mdb files it is working properly in both local drive and share drive.
While accessing *.accdb file I am able to connect in local drive.
But while trying to connect .accdb file in shared drive i am getting the error as "Could not find installable ISAM".

Here is the code I am trying,

```
strDBPath = "\\shared drive path\Database.accdb"

Set objConnection = New Connection    

With objConnection
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";" & _
        "Persist Security Info=False" & ";" & _
        "PWD=" & pass
        .Open
End With
```

Please provide a resolution to the query.

Regards,
Susanta Kumar Patra

Comment: What version of Office do you have?

Comment: Also, you might be missing a ";" after your password

Comment: Try `.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & pass`

Comment: You might also want to see [THIS](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007)

Comment: Thank you all for your kind support.
But unfortunately the issue is not resolved.
The issue I could not understand is it is working for the file stored in my local hard drive but only issue arises while accessing the file in shared drive.